# How can we correlate linked server queries running to their source instance?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We have multiple versions of SQL Server from 2008R2 (I know) to 2016.  There are many linked server queries.  I'm trying to build a tool that will tell me the queries executing on a target server that come from linked server queries executing on another source server.

**QUESTION #1)**

Can I rely on sys.dm_exec_sessions.program_name = 'Microsoft SQL Server'?

I've hesitated to go that route so far and have been relying on looking at the sql text:

```
dest.text LIKE '%"Tbl[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"%'
```

**QUESTION #2)**

Once I have found the linked server queries running on my target instance, I want to traverse back to the original calling instance.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Right now, I'm heading down the path of looking for the target instance in the sql text of queries running on the source host(s):

```
AND dest.text LIKE '%$LinkedServerName%'
```

(Not the variable expansion - this is a powershell snippet, not straight TSQL)

Still, I may have some interesting logic to truly say, "This query is what is causing the query to execute on my linked server" - not to mention the perf hit of the leading wildcard search into my sql text.

Ideas?

Thank you,

-Peter

Comment: Why not use the `host_name` of `sys.dm_exec_sessions`? If you don't have other apps running the remote database server, that would be linked server queries from that instance.

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman.  I'm already doing that.  I'm taking the host_name from the queries I find on the target server and looking at each of those servers for queries that hit the target server.